# AngularJs - ngRepeat Delete a particular line in View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple rendering of 3 items with their particular ids glued with there name fields. I want to show a particular message whenever I delete that line only with the button to follow. When I am doing it, I have problem in passing the id for delete for that particular line only, and all the n rows (here 3) are getting deleted.

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<div>
    <p ng-repeat="x in List" ng-show="!deleted">{{x.name}}<button ng-click="del(x.id)">Delete</button></p>
    <p ng-show="deleted">This line has been deleted.</p>
</div>

<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.deleted = false;
    $scope.List = [{"name":"Peter Martin","id":"1"},{"name":"Lita Schedan","id":"2"},{"name":"Jenni Markints","id":"3"}];
    $scope.del = function(id){
        //for this id -> only 
        $scope.deleted = true;
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This means, if I put delete button of line 2. The first and second rows must come with the delete button, but in the middle line the message "This line has been deleted" must show.

Comment: you have to use `.slice(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should basically show the row which has deleted `flag` false by using angular filter. For that you need to make sure you List object show have `deleted` prop to `false` on initial load. Then on click pass whole row object to `del` method. And for showing error message you could use `$timeout` that will show an message for half second

**Markup**

```
<div>
    <p ng-repeat="x in List | filter : {deleted: false}">
       {{x.name}}
       <button ng-click="del(x)">Delete</button>
    </p>
    <p ng-show="deleted">Line with id {{deletedId}} has been deleted.</p>
</div>
```

And on click of element make delete flag to `true`

**Controller**

```
//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.deleted = false;
    $scope.List = [{"name":"Peter Martin","id":"1"},{"name":"Lita Schedan","id":"2"},{"name":"Jenni Markints","id":"3"}];
    angular.forEach($scope.List, function(ele){
       ele.deleted = false;
    })
    $scope.del = function(x){ //passed object
        x.deleted = true;
        //for showing message
        $scope.deleted = true;
        $scope.deletedId = x.id;
        $timeout(function(){
           $scope.deleted = false;
           $scope.deletedId = undefined;
        }, 500)
    }
});
```

If you really wanted to remove element from the array you could use `.slice()` method by passing `$index` to it